# Proc means - Calculating the share / weight

Tags: sas, sas-studio

I am using a proc means to calculate the share of the payments made by business line, the data looks like this:

```
data Test;
input ID Business_Line Payment2017;
Datalines;
1 1 1000
2 1 2000
3 1 3000
4 1 4000
5 2 500
6 2 1500
7 2 3000
;
run;
```

i'm looking to calculate an additional column which, by group (business_line) calculates the percentage share (weight) of the payment as such:

```
   data Test;
input ID Business_Line Payment2017 share;
Datalines;
1 1 1000 0.1
2 1 2000 0.2
3 1 3000 0.3
4 1 4000 0.4
5 2 500 0.1
6 2 1500 0.3
7 2 3000 0.6
;
run;
```

the code I have used so far:

```
proc means data = test noprint;
class ID;
by business_line;
var Payment2017;
output out=test2 
sum = share;
weight = payment2017/share;
run;
```

I have also tried

```
proc means data = test noprint;
class ID;
by business_line;
var Payment2017 /weight = payment2017;
output out=test3 ;
run;
```

appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Proc FREQ` will compute percentages.  You can divide the `PERCENT` column of the output to get the fraction, or work with percents downstream.

In this example `id` crosses `payment2017` in order to ensure all original rows are part of the output.  If the `id` was not present, and there were any replicate payment amounts, `FREQ` would aggregate the payment amounts.

```
proc freq data=have noprint;
 by business_line;
 table id*payment2017 / out=want all;
 weight payment2017 ;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient to do with proc sql:

```
proc sql;
   select *, payment2017/sum(payment2017) as share from test group by business_line;
quit;
```

data step:

```
data have;
    do until (last.business_line);
    set test;
    by business_line notsorted;
    total+payment2017;
    end;
    do until (last.business_line);
    set test;
    by business_line notsorted;
    share=payment2017/total;
    output;
    end;
    call missing(total);
    drop total;
run;
```